# What is a better practice for extracting icons?

Tags: c#, winapi

I have created an explorer window that scans the directories upon loading for filetypes, etc. when it first loads, i use

```
internal static extern uint ExtractIconEx(string szFileName, uint nIconIndex, IntPtr[] phiconLarge, IntPtr[] phiconSmall, uint nIcons);
```

and

```
internal static unsafe extern int DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);
```

to scan for currently registered icons and then i associate them with teh files im using. it works fine on my machine but when i run it on others, i get a low resource error. 
so my question is what is a better practice? to go the way that i am, and load them all up, or everytime i need to enumerate a directory to look for the filetype and associate it.

Comment: What makes you think that the icons are the source of your resource problems? How many icons is your program loading? How many is it freeing? Can you show the relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could do this with system.drawing

```
var icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"c:\xxx\some.file");
```

(You would need to resize this for the small shell size)